# Update vector inside reduce

Tags: clojure

Given a vector:

```
(def vec [{:key 1, :value 10, :other "bla"}, {:key 2, :value 13, :other "bla"}, {:key 1, :value 7, :other "bla"}])
```

I'd like to iterate over each element and update `:value` with the sum of all `:value`s to that point, so I would have:

```
[{:key 1, :value 10, :other "bla"}, {:key 2, :value 23, :other "bla"}, {:key 1, :value 30, :other "bla"}])
```

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359713/how-do-i-operate-on-every-item-in-a-vector-and-refer-to-a-previous-value-in-cloj) for printing the result, but I've tried to change the `prn` command to `update-in`, `assoc-in` in the code below (extracted from the link above) but I didn't work quite well.

```
(reduce (fn [total {:keys [key value]}]
                  (let [total (+ total value)]
                    (prn key total)
                    total))
              0 vec)
```

I'm new to Clojure, how can I make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the running totals then the simplest way is to use `reductions`:

```
(reductions (fn [acc ele] (+ acc (:value ele))) 
            0
            [{:key 1, :value 10, :other "bla"}, {:key 2, :value 13, :other "bla"}, {:key 1, :value 7, :other "bla"}])
;; => (0 10 23 30)
```

As you can see the function you pass to `reductions` has the same signature as the function you pass to a `reduce`. It is like you are asking for a `reduce` to be done every time a new element is reached. Another way of thinking about it is that every time a new accumulator is calculated it is kept, unlike with `reduce` where the caller only gets to see the result of the last calculation.

And so this is the code that would directly answer your question:

```
(->> [{:key 1, :value 10, :other "bla"}, {:key 2, :value 13, :other "bla"}, {:key 1, :value 7, :other "bla"}]
     (reductions #(update %2 :value + (:value %1))
                 {:value 0})
     next
     vec)
;; => [{:key 1, :value 10, :other "bla"} {:key 2, :value 23, :other "bla"} {:key 1, :value 30, :other "bla"}]
```

Comment: `#(update %2 :value + (:value %1))` for less `:value`

Comment: Thanks - if the RHS of an `assoc` is referring to what are *assoc-ing* on then the smell can be corrected by having an `update` instead. Will make the fix now.

Comment: There's an extra parentheses after vec but, except that, it works just fine :)

Answer (score 1):

You can accumulate the `:value`s thus:

```
(reductions + (map :value v))
=> (10 23 30)
```

(I renamed the vector `v` to avoid tripping over `clojure.core/vec`.)

Then you can use `mapv` over `assoc`:

```
(let [value-sums (reductions + (map :value v))]
  (mapv #(assoc %1 :value %2) v value-sums))
=> [{:key 1, :value 10, :other "bla"} {:key 2, :value 23, :other "bla"} {:key 1, :value 30, :other "bla"}]
```